# (document).load throwing a syntax error

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery

I am new jQuery & Ajax. I wrote a code using jQuery and it is working fine.
But the thing is I am getting a warning message like "Syntax Error". I want to get rid of this warning too, please help me from this

I am getting a warning message near EntityId field. Just verify the syntax of load function. Thanks in advance

Comment: looks like you may have to wrap `@Model.EntityId.EntityId` with in `''` like `'@Model.EntityId.EntityId'`

Comment: I'll post it as the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looks like you may have to wrap `@Model.EntityId.EntityId` with in `''` like `'@Model.EntityId.EntityId'`